# No funciona el File.rename

Tags: java, archivo, filewriter

Tengo este código:

```
File antiguo = new File("Sistema\\Personajes\\" + inicialNombreCompleto + ".json");
                    File nuevo = new File("Sistema\\Personajes\\" + personaje.getString("Nombre completo") + ".json");
                    
                    if(antiguo.renameTo(nuevo))
                        System.out.print("Si");
                    else
                        System.out.print("No");
     
                    try {
                        FileWriter escribe = new FileWriter(nuevo, false);
                        escribe.write(personaje.toString());
                        escribe.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Básicamente lo que quiero es hacer el rename, pero no importa lo que haga, nunca me lo hace, se quedan los 2 archivos, ¿por qué sucede esto?

Answer (score 0):

El problema puede estar en la ruta. Modificando levemente tu código no hay problema a la hora de renombrar el archivo.

```
package archivos;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.File;

public class Main{
    //Creamos una ruta donde estara el archivo a renombrar
    public static final String RUTA = "/home/user/Documentos/app/src/main/resources";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File antiguo = new File(RUTA+"/data.csv");
        File nuevo = new File(RUTA+"/copia.csv");

        //Verificamos que existe
        if(antiguo.exists()){
          //Si data.csv existe, se renombra
            if(antiguo.renameTo(nuevo)){
                System.out.print("Se ha renombrado el archivo: "+antiguo.getName());
            }else{
                System.out.print("No se pudo renombrar el archivo: "+antiguo.getName());
                try {
                    FileWriter escribe = new FileWriter(nuevo, false);
                    //Escribimos en el archivo
                    escribe.write("Nuevos datos");
                    escribe.close();
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Espero te sirva.